# Send e-mail over smtp and change the sender's name

Tags: email, go, smtp, mail-sender

I am sending e-mails over smtp in golang, which works perfectly fine. To set the sender of an e-mail I use the [Client.Mail](http://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#Client.Mail) funtion:

```
func (c *Client) Mail(from string) error
```

When the recipient gets the e-mail he sees the sender as plaintext e-mail address: `sender@example.com`

I want the sender to be displayed like: `Sandy Sender <sender@example.com>`.

Is this possible? I tried setting the sender to `Sandy Sender <sender@example.com>` or only `Sandy Sender` but none of them work. I get the error `501 5.1.7 Invalid address`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to set the `From` field of your mail to `Sandy Sender <sender@example.com>`:

```
...
From: Sandy Sender <sender@example.com>
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Hello!

This is the body of the message.
```

And use the address only (`sender@example.com`) in `Client.Mail`.

Alternatively, you can use my package [Gomail](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail):

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"
)

func main() {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetAddressHeader("From", "sender@example.com", "Sandy Sender")
    m.SetAddressHeader("To", "recipient@example.com")
    m.SetHeader("Subject", "Hello!")
    m.SetBody("text/plain", "This is the body of the message.")

    d := gomail.NewPlainDialer("smtp.example.com", 587, "user", "123456")

    if err := d.DialAndSend(m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: So with go I can send multiple emails via one smtp connection?

Comment: You can with Gomail v2 (still unstable): https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail/issues/10#issuecomment-122090752

Comment: @codingrogue Gomail v2 is now out and supports sending multiple emails with a single SMTP connection. Have a look at the Newsletter example: https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2#example-package--Newsletter

Answer (score 1):

You can add `"From: EmailName<" + EmailAdderss + "> \r\n"` to mail header to show whatever EmailName you want, and add Email Address to void duplicate mail.

Comment: Also, a bit low-level, compared to the other answers...

Comment: Yeah, It use for smtp package only. Not using any other package. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a project like [`jpoehls/gophermail`](https://github.com/jpoehls/gophermail) works better.

It has a test case [like this one](https://github.com/jpoehls/gophermail/blob/e78d63e93435075c1191a8b45f2599bc914774da/main_test.go#L11):

```
m.SetFrom("Domain Sender <sender@domain.com>")
```

It internally ([`main.go`](https://github.com/jpoehls/gophermail/blob/e78d63e93435075c1191a8b45f2599bc914774da/main.go#L80)) calls in [`SetMailAddress()`](https://github.com/jpoehls/gophermail/blob/e78d63e93435075c1191a8b45f2599bc914774da/main.go#L80) the method [`mail.ParseAddress()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/mail/#ParseAddress) which is [supposed to follow](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/mail/message.go?s=3592:3643#L132) [RFC 5322](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5322).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [mail.Address](http://godoc.org/net/mail#Address) and use [Address.String](http://godoc.org/net/mail#Address.String) function formats the address

```
func (a *Address) String() string
```

> String formats the address as a valid RFC 5322 address. If the address's name contains non-ASCII characters the name will be rendered according to RFC 2047.

and I write example:

[go_smtp.go](https://gist.github.com/lidashuang/af7725bd1dd7392b31b2)